# Why is a StreamBuilder modifying a final variable set outside of it by a FutureBuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have the below code, where a `FutureBuilder` loads some data that is a `Map<String, dynamic>`. While the `FutureBuilder` is loading, it returns a loading spinner. After the future completes with the data, it returns a `StreamBuilder` that listens to a Firestore query. The print statements output the following in the console:

```
Future build: {'abc': {'type': 1, 'color': 'red'}, 'def': {'type': 2, 'color': 'blue'}}
Stream build: {'abc': {'type': 1, 'color': 'red'}, 'def': {'type': 2, 'color': 'blue'}}
Stream build 2: {'abc': {'type': 1, 'color': 'red'}, 'def': {'type': 2, 'color': 'blue'}}
Stream build: {'abc': {'type': 1, 'color': 'red'}, 'def': {'type': 2, 'color': 'blue'}}
Stream build 2: {'abc': {'type': 1, 'color': 'red'}, 'def': {'type': 2, 'color': 'blue'}}
Stream build 3: {'abc': {'type': 1, 'color': 'red'}}
```

```
return FutureBuilder(
    future: _future,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }

      final info = snapshot.data;

      print('Future build: $info');

      return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        stream: _stream,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snap) {
          print('Stream build: $info');

          if (snap.hasError) {
            return const Center(
              child: Text('An error occurred.'),
            );
          }

          print('Stream build 2: $info');

          if (!snap.hasData) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }

          print('Stream build 3: $info');
        });
      });
```

My question is, how is the second element of the Map getting deleted on the second build of the `StreamBuilder`? The variable is even final! There are no other places in the code where the `info` variable is set, and no other variables sharing that name.

I understand why the `StreamBuilder` builds twice, and on the first build does not reach the `Stream build 3` print. But I cannot understand why it would be modifying the variable set by the previous `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: By the time you get StreamBuilder and FutureBuilder nested, you've graduated to the point where you should be using Riverpod, and never need a FutureBuilder or StreamBuilder again.

Comment: It would be pointless to add an entire package to an app for a single instance of a nested streambuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Did you override the `toString` method of your `info` class to modify something?

Or did you not include the full code, or the complete logs?

Because otherwise there is no way that the code

```dart
          print('Stream build 2: $info');

          if (!snap.hasData) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }

          print('Stream build 3: $info');
```

leads to this output:

```dart
Stream build 2: {'abc': {'type': 1, 'color': 'red'}, 'def': {'type': 2, 'color': 'blue'}}
Stream build 3: {'abc': {'type': 1, 'color': 'red'}}
```

That would not be possible in dart.

Comment: I did not, it's just a regular Map<String, dynamic>. I even tried assigning the same data to an additional final variable at the same location, using a new variable name (in case something was happening to the other variable). Same result.

Comment: Then please create a reproducible example code snippet that i can directly run without modifying which then should result in the same behaviour.